# Hadoop Java Error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Titanic

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run a simple MapReduce program which calculates the average age of male and female. When i am trying to execute it, it is giving me Class Not Found Exception (Titanic class). I have found many questions which has provided the similar answer and based on that i have modified my program but still it's giving me same error. It would be really helpfull if anyone can debug it.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class Titanic{
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
    private Text category = new Text();
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text text, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        String line = text.toString();
        String str[] = line.split(",");
        if(str[4] == "male"){
            category.set(str[4]);
        }else{
            category.set(str[4]);
        }
        IntWritable value = new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(str[5]));
        context.write(category,value);
    }

}

public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, FloatWritable>{

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        float average = 0;
        int count =0;
        for(IntWritable val : values){
                average = average+val.get();
                count = count + 1;              
        }
        average =average/count;
        context.write(key, new FloatWritable(average));

    }   

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "titanic");
    job.setJarByClass(Titanic.class);
    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);       
}
```

}

below are the commands i have executed on it.

creating a jar file:

```
jar cf example/titanic/titanic.jar example/titanic/Titanic*.class
```

executing a jar file:

```
bin/hadoop jar example/titanic/titanic.jar Titanic /user/akhil/titanic/input/TitanicData.txt /user/akhil/titanic/output/
```

Comment: Which class isn't found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jar has is messed up. If your classes belong to the default package, they should not be located under `example/titanic/` directories but rather under root directory.

Comment: My Titanic.java file is under /example/titanic folder. When i compiled it it has created 3 class files under /example/titanic folder. So i have created the jar file under the same folder and ran it. Since i don't have package statement, it has the default package.

Comment: Well, to fix that you can either leave the classes in the default package but run `cd example/titanic && jar cf titanic.jar *.class && cd -` and run same hadoop command; OR add `package example.titanic;` statement at the first line of your java class, recompile and re-package, then run `bin/hadoop jar example/titanic/titanic.jar example.titanic.Titanic /user/akhil/titanic/input/TitanicData.txt /user/akhil/titanic/output/`.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html

Answer (score 0):

Remove the * :

```
jar cf example/titanic/titanic.jar example/titanic/Titanic.class
```

Comment: Still same error. There are other class as well like Titanic$Map.class and Titanic$Reduce.class, so * include all of them. I guess these files needs to be included in jar.